# On the relationship between Fermats Last Theorem and Elliptic Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have to give a presentation on elliptic curves in general. It does not have to be very in depth. I have a very basic understanding of elliptic curves (The most I understand is the concept of ranks). I was wondering if anyone could explain to me simply what is the connection between the equation $x^n +y^n=z^n$ and elliptic curves.

Comment: This question is also posted on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103577/on-the-relationship-between-fermats-last-theorem-and-eliptical-curve

Comment: I may be wrong, but I do not think there is a simple explanation.

Answer (score 18):

Given non-zero integers $A,$ $B$, and $C$, such that $A + B = C$, we can form the
so-called [*Frey curve*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frey_curve) (named after the mathematician Frey, who first considered
elliptic curves in the context of FLT)

$$E: y^2 = x(x-A)(x+B),$$

which has discriminant (up to some power of $2$ which one can compute precisely, but which I will ignore here) equal to $ABC$.

Suppose now that $A = a^p$, $B = b^p$, and $C = c^p$ (so that we have a solution
to the Fermat equation of exponent $p$).  Then the elliptic curve $E$ has
a discriminant which (up to the power of $2$ that I am ignoring) is a perfect $p$th power.

This means that the group of $p$-torsion points $E[p]$ on $E$ (which is a two-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb F_p$ of $p$-elements, equipped with an action of the Galois group of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ over $\mathbb Q$) 
has very special properties --- in algebraic number theory terms, it is very close to being unramified.  (More specifically, but more technically, it is unramified except possibly at $2$ and $p$, and at $p$ the ramification is very mild --- it is finite flat.)

Now the Shimura--Taniyama conjecture, which is what Wiles (together with Taylor)
proved, shows that $E$, and so $E[p]$, arises from a weight two modular form.  Ribet's earlier results on Serre's epsilon conjecture imply that this modular 
form must actually be of level $2$. (This is where we use the above information about the ramification.)   But there are no non-zero cuspforms of weight $2$ and level $2$, and we get a contradiction.

Although it is much harder (in that the only way we know to rule out the existence of $E[p]$ is by the --- quite difficult --- Shimura--Taniyama 
conjecture, or else by related more recent results such as Khare and Wintenberger's work on Serre's conjecture), one can think of the non-existence
of $E[p]$ as being analogous to Minkowski's theorem in algebraic number theory, which says that an everywhere-unramified extension of $\mathbb Q$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 4):

There are certainly people on this site that are much more capable than I am of explaining the connection competently, so I'll stick to providing a reference. The last chapter of Diamond-Shurman's  *A First Course in Modular Forms* gives an overview of how this story goes, at the level of a graduate-level textbook (of course, given the scope of the result, they have to black-box many, many things). They explain how to construct the Frey curve, which is an elliptic curve associated to a hypothetical solution to Fermat's equation, and they show how the theory of modular forms (in particular the Taylor-Wiles result that all elliptic curves are *modular* in the sense that they have an "associated" modular form) allows one to show that no such Frey curves can exist (very briefly, if a Frey curve existed, its associated modular form would have to live in a particular space of forms which one can show directly to be empty).