# Why Frey's curve cannot be constructed?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

My question is related to the fact that Frey's curve:

$$y^{2} = x(x-a^{p})(x+b^{p})$$

Could not be constructed if Fermat's last theorem holds true. I mean because Fermat's last theorem implies that there is no solution for $a$, $b$, $c$, and prime number $p > 2$ such that:

$$a^{p}+b^{p}=c^{p}$$

As a result the Frey's curve which is semi-stable elliptic curve could be not constructed because according to Ribet's theorem this curve is not modular but Taniyama-Shimura-Weil conjecture implies that each elliptic curve should be modular. The thing I can't understand that is when we say Frey's curve could not be constructed in what sense it could not be constructed? I mean the equation $y^{2} = x(x-a^{p})(x+b^{p})$ contains only $a^{p}$ and $b^{p}$ but it's not completely symmetric to contain all $a$, $b$, $c$ in a symmetric way. I appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the entire point of the Frey curve is that the pairwise distances between the three places it crosses the $x$-axis are $a^p, b^p$ and $a^p+b^p$. If $a^p+b^p=c^p$, then all three distances (and therefore the _discriminant_) are $p$th powers, and somehow such an elliptic curve cannot have an associated modular form. It's been a while since I last heard a lecture on the subject, though, so I'm somewhat uncertain on the details.

Comment: You mean its roots are $a^{p}$, $b^{p}$, and $c^{p}$? I don’t think so...

Comment: No, the roots are $0, a^p$ and $-b^p$, obviously. That much you can read off directly from $y^2=x(x-a^p)(x+b^p)$. Now, what are the pairwise distances between those three roots?

Comment: You can certainly write down the curve $y^2 = x(x - a^p)(x + b^p)$. But this curve is not called a Frey curve unless there is a $c$ such that $a^p + b^p = c^p$ (and $p \ge 3$), and since there is never such a $c$, there aren't any Frey curves.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think you have the logic reversed there. It's supposed to be "and since there are no Frey curves, you never have $a^p+b^p=c^p$".

Comment: I don't think there is a simple explanation. If it was too much obvious there should not be such an advanced proof for $\epsilon$-conjecture by Ribet. I mean it may needs a lot of effort to show that constructing Frey's curve based on triples of that Diophantine equation will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: No, the construction of the curve itself is really as straight-forward as this. Proving that the curve cannot exist is where the work lies.

Comment: Ok, so I think if someone could write Frey's curve in terms of a complex value (i.e. $z = x + i y$) function $f(z)$, that would may help to check why it cannot be constructed. Any idea about complex form of Frey's curve or maybe I'm wrong?!

Comment: There are some explanations here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2325116?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Also see this: http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ta/ta-flt.pdf

Comment: It seems that you need to specify **what** field the points of the curve are members of. It is a perfectly valid curve over the complex or real fields. But if the field is rational or finite then that is another story. In any case, it always has the point $x=y=0.$

Answer (score 12):

In 1969 Hellegouarch performed the elliptic curves $F (a, b)$, which were later named after Gerhard Frey and were constructed from the solutions of the Fermat equation, he reported on the curves in an article in Acta Arithmetica. I have found the [article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa26/aa2636.pdf) but it is not in English.

Let me give you a over-simplified version taken form the lecture-series ["Riemann Hypothesis and its Applications" (Lecture-29)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYfSo7Xq0Jc&t=325s) by Prof. Manindra Agrawal, Department of Computer Science and Engineering, IIT Kanpur (won the 2006 Fulkerson Prize, and the 2006 Gödel Prize for the AKS primality test).

**First Step**

Let $F:= y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, then discriminant $\Delta_F=(ab)^2+4a^3c-4b^3+18abc-27c^3.$

If $c=0$, then $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$, $\Delta_F=(ab)^2-4b^3.$

**Now the Frey's curve is** , $y^2=x(x-A)(x+B)=(x^2-Ax)(x+B)=x^3-Ax^2+Bx^2-ABx.$

Let, $a=(B-A), b=-AB,$ then $\Delta= \{(B-A)(-AB)\}^2-4(-AB)^3= \{(B-A)^2-4(-AB)\}(-AB)^2=(A^2+B^2-2AB+4Ab)(AB)^2=(A+B)^2(AB)^2.$

Now, let, $A=a^q, B=b^q,$ then, $\Delta_F=(a^q+b^q)^2(ab)^{2q},$

**if** $a^q+b^q=c^q$ **is true** for $q>2$ **(this is Fermat's last theorem)**,

then the discriminant $\Delta_F=(c^q)^2(ab)^{2q}=(abc)^{2q}.$

**Second Step**

If $\Delta_F$ is $l^{th}$ power of an integer, then it has a point of order $l$. **If** $a^q+b^q=c^q$ **is true for** $q>2$, then the Frey curve $F$ has a point a point of order $2q$, since it's discriminant $\Delta_F$ is $2q^{th}$ power of an integer $(abc)$.

**Third Step**

But if $F$ is modular, then, it does not have a point of order $ > C$ where $C$ is a constant.

**Fourth Step**

It has been proved that every elliptic curve is modular ([Taniyama–Shimura conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem), Andrew Wiles proved the Taniyama–Shimura conjecture for semistable elliptic curves, which was enough to imply Frey curve is modular).

**Final Step**

Since Frey curve $F$ is modular, then it can not have a point of order $ \geq C$, but the Frey curve $F$'s discriminant $\Delta_F$ is $2q^{th}$ power of an integer $(abc)$, so $q$ can not be $> \frac{C}{2}$, does there could not be solution $a^q+b^q=c^q$ for $q> \frac{C}{2}$, i.e. there are finite $q$ for which Fermat's Last Theorem is true.

*Frey's curve can not be constructed since by the definition of the Frey's Curve, it must have a point of order $2q$ but at the same time it is an elliptic curve, thus modular, so, the Frey's Curve can not have a point of order $ \geq C$, so after certain value of $q$, Frey's curve can not be constructed.*

Of-course I have missed many intricate details for the sake of accessibility.

**In a bit more technical terms:** The group of $p$-torsion points $F[p]$ on $F$
(which is a two-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb F_p$ of $p$-elements),

equipped with an action of the Galois group of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ over $\mathbb Q$)  has very special properties,

in algebraic number theory terms, it is very close to being unramified, specifically, but more technically, it is unramified except possibly at $2$ and $p$, and at $p$ the ramification is very mild, it is finite flat.

Now the Shimura-Taniyama conjecture, which is what Wiles (together with Taylor)
proved, shows that $F$, and so $F[p]$, arises from a weight two modular form.  Ribet's earlier results on Serre's epsilon conjecture imply that this modular
form must actually be of level $2$. (This is where we use the above information about the ramification.)   But there are no non-zero cuspforms of weight $2$ and level $2$, and we get a contradiction.

Although it is much harder (in that the only way we know to rule out the existence of $F[p]$ is by the - quite difficult- Shimura-Taniyama
conjecture, or else by related more recent results such as Khare and Wintenberger's work on Serre's conjecture), one can think of the non-existence
of $F[p]$ as being analogous to Minkowski's theorem in algebraic number theory, which says that an everywhere-unramified extension of $\mathbb Q$ cannot exist (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177044/179940)).

**For detail proof, read following books:**

*1. Fermat's Last Theorem: Basic Tools by Takeshi Saito
(Publication Year: 2013),*

*2. Fermat's Last Theorem: The Proof by Takeshi Saito (Publication Year: 2014).*

Comment: Your answer is not up to the level of expectation, 3rd and 4th step is unclear, however I am awarding the bounty, not because you deserve it, because, otherwise it will be wasted.